# What is implied by the handling of multisets by N-modules?

Tags: category-theory, monads

Multisets are containers, also called bags.  A multiset is a set that can have repeats:

$$\{ a, a, a, c, b, c \}$$

Usually when researchers talk about multisets, they use this kind of presentation:

$$ \psi = 3| a \rangle + 2| c \rangle + | b \rangle $$

In fact, $\psi$ is actual an element of an $\mathbb{N}$-module.  $\mathbb{N}$-modules are the Eilenberg-Moore category of the multiset monad.  Why do researchers always represent multisets as $\mathbb{N}$-modules?  What is the deep implication here?

Comment: It is a convenient interpretation. If e.g the element b  occurs 4566 times, writing it as 4566b is easier than using the set-like notation. It also blends well with the union of multisets as ordinary sum.